# Try Catch outside of: await Task.Run(()

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, async-await

Does try catch outside of: `await Task.Run(() =>` make sense or just use them only inside of await?

```
private async void Test()
{
     try
     {
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                  DoingSomething();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                  log.Error(ex.Message);
             }
         });
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          log.Error(ex.Message);
      }
}
```

Comment: That completely depends on how you can handle the error.

Comment: Also, never write `async void`.

Comment: I intend to catch all errors insie od await but is it safer to add Try Catch outside too?

Comment: @SLaks What's wrong with `async void` (or how is it different from any other void method)?

Comment: @user2864740: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you handle `Exception` inside the delegate (in your case just for logging purpose), `await` will not raise an exception in normal circumstances. This should be fine.

```
private async Task Test()
{
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                  DoingSomething();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                  log.Error(ex.Message);
             }
         });

}
```

However, since you are `await`ing the `Task`, most probably, there will be some `DoSomethingElse` in the  `Test` method, which might be affected by the outcome of the `Task` - in which case it also makes sense to have a `try/catch` around `await`.

```
private async Task Test()
{
     try
     {
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                  DoingSomething();
             }
             catch (SomeSpecialException spex)
             {
                  // it is OK to have this exception
                  log.Error(ex.Message);
             }
         });

         DoSomethingElse(); // does not run when unexpected exception occurs.
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          // Here we are also running on captured SynchronizationContext
          // So, can update UI to show error ....
      }
}
```

Comment: I tried this in a console app, and put a break in the catch, it was not in the main thread, I throw again and nothing happens. I want the main thread to get the exception. how can I do this?

Comment: @pogorman Console app does not have a SynchronizationContext, so code after await can run on any thread. If your actual application is WPF or WinForms, exception would be raised back on main thread

Comment: what is the best strategy for a console app? If an exception occurs in the background I want the app to crash hard so that errors are swallowed up silently. Thanks.

Comment: ideally I want the app to crash hard on any unexpected exception.

Comment: @pogorman, which is default behaviour, unless your thread is marked as background thread

Comment: yes - I really want exceptions thrown within a Task.Run to crash the whole app. I can't find a way to do this though on a console app.

Comment: @pogorman - exception within `Task.Run` will be raised only when you `await` the `Task` returned from `Task.Run`. If you dont `await` or dont try to get result from that `task` then exception will be swallowed.

Answer (score 14):

If the delegate you pass to `Task.Run` raises an exception, then you can catch it outside the `Task.Run` when you `await` the returned task.

You shouldn't think of `await` as though it was a block. There's no such thing as "inside of await". Instead, think of `await` as an operator that takes a single argument (in this case, the `Task` returned by `Task.Run`). `Task.Run` will catch exceptions from its delegate and place them on the returned `Task`; `await` will then propagate that exception.

Comment: You can only catch exception outside if delegate is marked as async (
even if there is no await statement in delegate) `await Task.Run(async () => { throw new Exception("msg"); });`

Comment: @Arvis: No, you can catch it without the `async` inside `Task.Run`.

Comment: I just ran into this same situation. I could not catch an `SQLException` outside of `Task.Run` unless I added the `async` keyword to my lambda

Comment: @NonSecwitter It's probably only the debugger that stops on an exception that "was unhanded by user code".

Answer (score 2):

You can add try catch to outside code too. The compiler will execute catch section when an exception happens during the async call. Here is more details why would you need try catch around await http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx look Exceptions in Async Methods

Answer (score -1):

This is the behavior in .Net 6:

```
try{
 await Task.Run(()=>   & call whatever method    );
}
catch { handle the exception }          <-- the catch will never get hit. An unhandled exception in the Task.Run line will happen
```

However, this will work:

```
try{
await Task.Run(async ()=> & call some method );
}
catch(Exception ex){
   handle the exception
}
```

The async before the ()=> has to be there for .Net 6

I've just confirmed this.